# Load JVM in a DLL

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

I am loading JVM in a dll but it fails (indicated in the code where it fails.). I tried the same code in an exe and it works fine.

```
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK 1.1 VM initialization arguments */
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVMOption options;
  options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Core\\bin\\otk-1.4.1-with-dependencies.jar";

  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; 
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.options = &options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

  jvm_dll = LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");
  if(jvm_dll == NULL) 
  { 
getManager()->log( "InitialiseJava::Can't Load JVM DLL.", HIGH_IMPORTANCE );
return false;
  }  

  JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr = (JNI_CreateJavaVM_func)GetProcAddress(jvm_dll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
 if(JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr == NULL) 
{ 
getManager()->log( "InitialiseJava::Can't create JVM.", HIGH_IMPORTANCE );
return false;
}

int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); // fails here
if(ret < 0)
{
getManager()->log( "InitialiseJava::Unable to call JVM.", HIGH_IMPORTANCE );
return false;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Define "fails". Crashes? Returns an error code?

Comment: variable ret is less than 0 which means it logs "Unable to call JVM"

Comment: My function returns false because the value of variable 'ret' is less than zero. There is no runtime error due to error handling

Comment: Is your code called at library initialization or is it called in a method invoked from an actual exe ?

Comment: If you are running on Vista or Windows 7, you may have some fickle UAC issues going on.  I have been having similar issues between running an install directly from within an executable, as opposed to calling from within a dll that is called by an exe.  Try running the exe that calls the dll with elevated privedges (right click, run elevated)

Comment: This code is in a dll which is called by an exe. The exe is actually a windows service. 
The code is called at dll initialization and not by any method invoked by the exe. Should that make any difference?
I am running XP

Comment: There is very little that is safe to perform during DLL initialization. Microsoft makes that very clear in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx): "Warning  There are serious limits on what you can do in a DLL entry point. To provide more complex initialization, create an initialization routine for the DLL. You can require applications to call the initialization routine before calling any other routines in the DLL."